# Elasticsearch: Find substring match, Exact match and only if present match

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to perform such kind of query such that the query shows output if and only if all the words in the query are present in the given string as a string or query
For example -

> let text = "garbage can"

so if I query

> "garb"

it should return "garbage can"

if I query

> "garbage ca"

it should return "garbage can"

but if I query

> "garbage b"

it should not return anything

I tried using ***substring*** and also ***match*** but they both did not quite did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do a [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html). please try the following **prefix query**:

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "my_keyword": {
        "value": "garbage b"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this kind of prefix query's performance is not good.

You could try the following query by **using customized prefix analyser**.
First, create a new index:

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "autocomplete_filter": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": "1",
            "max_gram": "20"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "autocomplete_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_text": {
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "type": "text"
      },
      "my_keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second, insert data into this index:

```
PUT /test_index/_doc/1
{
  "my_text": "garbage can",
  "my_keyword": "garbage can"
}
```

Query with "garbage c"

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "my_text": "garbage c"
    }
  }
}

{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.45802015,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.45802015,
        "_source" : {
          "my_text" : "garbage can",
          "my_keyword" : "garbage can"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Query with "garbage b"

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "my_text": "garbage b"
    }
  }
}

{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

**If you don't want to do a prefix query**, you could try the following **wildcard query**. Please remember the performance is bad and you could also try to use customeized analyser to optimize it.

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "my_keyword": {
        "value": "*garbage c*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

> **New Edit Part**

I'm not sure if I got want you really want this time....

Anyway, please try to use the following _mapping and queries:

> **1. Create Index**

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 50,
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "autocomplete_filter": {
            "type": "ngram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 51,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "autocomplete_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_text": {
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "type": "text"
      },
      "my_keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> **2. Insert some smaple data**

```
PUT /test_index/_doc/1
{
  "my_text": "test garbage can",
  "my_keyword": "test garbage can"
}

PUT /test_index/_doc/2
{
  "my_text": "garbage",
  "my_keyword": "garbage"
}
```

> **3. Query**

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "my_text": "bage c"
    }
  }
}
```

> **Please Note:**
>
> 1. This index only support string which max length is 50. Otherwise you need to modified `max_ngram_diff`, `min_gram` and `max_gram`
> 2. It need a lot of mem to build the reversing index

Comment: does it match `garbage an`?

Comment: it doesn't. Do you mean it should match `garbage an`?

Comment: I just suspected that OP may want that.

Comment: Got it. waiting for @Ayush to make it more clear for us

Comment: yes I was thinking it must also match that, and also if I search "can" it should show results, but with this it shows no results (It only looks for prefix matches). Sorry my bad, should have been more clear.

Comment: @Ayush, have you try the wild card query? For example, if you want to search `garbage an`, you could use `"*garbage *c*"` as the search patten. I'm also a little confuse about what you want. Could you let me know more clearly. Because matching `"can"` is different with matching `garbage an` for a given `garbage can`

Comment: @Zhiyong I meant to say that we can also search any word in between as well, but in your implementation, we are able to search only the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an Edge N-gram tokenizer to index your data.
You can also have custom token_chars in the latest 7.8 version!

Have a look at the documentation for more details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html